# React Native Android Programming: Extending from two libraries in MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, react-native

I was following the configuration guide for `react-native-splash-screen` and eventually came across the following [instruction](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen#third-stepplugin-configuration):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

My problem is our current source code already extends from `react-native-navigation`'s `SplashActivity`. I'm aware that I can't extend a class from two or more superclasses. How do I reconcile this need? I come from primarily a Javascript programming background.

```
import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {...}
```

There are other resources about this, but I'm looking for an answer from someone who can answer from a standpoint of a `react-native` programming experience since I have minimal exposure to Java or native Android development.

Comment: is `SplashActivity` an interface?

Comment: @Benjamin nope, [seems to be an abstract class](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativenavigation/controllers/SplashActivity.java).

Comment: You can only implement interfaces, never abstract classes.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to do `MainActivity implements SplashActivity, ReactActivity` but seems like that was invalid. It is actually `extends`.

Comment: @Andres exactly so I don't see the issue in this question: just extends `ReactActivity` and implements `SplashActivity `

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Source Code of React's [SplashActivity](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativenavigation/controllers/SplashActivity.java), there isn't much going on. Could you not simply let `MainActivity` extend `ReactActivity` and manually mix in the code for React's `SplashActivity`?

I am aware that this is not an ideal solution, especially in case the implementation of React's `SplashActivity` may change, however, this seems to be the only option available at the moment.

You could create an issue on `ReactNative's` Github asking that the SplashActivity code be plugin-able.

Answer (score 1):

The main goal of `react-native-navigation SplashActivity`is to provide an easy way to show a splash screen (by implementing `createSplashLayout()` or `getSplashLayout()`, See https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/android-specific-use-cases?id=splash-screen).
If you don't specifically need a feature in `react-native-splash-screen` I would recommend using the `SplashActivity` as I don't see any way to make them work together for now.